# Collada - does ordering of transforms matter?

Tags: collada

If I have a set of transorms, made of translates, scale and rotates... will ordering of them matter? If I do translate and then rotate, will the result be different than rotate and translate?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen http://collada.org/public_forum/showthread.php/1016-order-of-transform ?

The thread gets a bit deep, but contains two essential points: the COLLADA spec wants you to transform in a certain order, and rotation and translation are not commutative, so order matters.

Edit - some details from the link:

The original poster refers to the COLLADA spec, I believe he paraphrases this part:

> The  element represents a context in which the child
>   transformation elements are composed in the order that they occur. All
>   the other child elements are affected equally by the accumulated
>   transformations in the scope of the  element. The transformation
>   elements transform the coordinate system of the  element.
>   Mathematically, this means that the transformation elements are
>   converted to matrices and postmultiplied in the order in which they
>   are specified within the  to compose the coordinate system.

In other words, the order of transformation is supposed to follow the order of the transformation elements in the document.

Herbert then answers by showing the actual matrix multiplication for a given example of nested transforms. His second post contains the correct order:

> M = (T1A x T1B x T1C) x (T2A x T2B x T2C) x (T3A x T3B x T3C)

Comment: Could you please provide some information from the link that answers the question explicitly?  What is the order for transform dependent on?

Comment: I edited my answer with additional detail from the linked conversation. I hope it's explicit enough now.