# Collada transformation numbers

Tags: collada

I have the following translations provided by COLLADA file:

```
<matrix sid="transform">1 0 0 0 0 -1 1.27952e-6 0 0 -1.27952e-6 -1 2 0 0 0 1</matrix>
```

I'm not sure I understand them, even after reading this post: [Collada - does ordering of transforms matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251168/collada-does-ordering-of-transforms-matter)

I understand translations can consist of:

- translation
- scaling
- rotation

but I can only imagine that's 9 numbers? `(sx, sy, sz) * (rx, ry, rz) * (tx, ty, tz)`

I could also understand that it must tell us the order of transformations to do but I do not see the relevance from the above numbers?

Could ya help me out?

Comment: This is a transformation matrix. Order matters.

Comment: Do you know which numbers represent which bit?

Comment: See page 5-77 of the 1.4 spec PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a matrix notation for objects 3D orientation:

```
matrix = { 0, 4, 8, 12,
           1, 5, 9, 13,
           2, 6, 10, 14,
           3, 7, 11, 15 }
```

where the given matrix is of the form :

```
<matrix sid="transform"> 0 1 2 3 4 ... 15 </matrix>
```

This worked for me in OpenGL

Comment: I am not so sure about that. Collada docs say that the order is the row/column, in your example it would be 0, 4, 8, 12, 1, 4, ...

Comment: @SpaceDog I think now this is the correct format. thanks

Comment: ah, I see. Thanks.